# My jQuery animate won't reposition

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to reposition a button whenever it is clicked, but i can't get the damn thing to move... I can rescale it, but it just won't move...

My code looks like this:

```
$('#test').on('click', function() {
    $(this).animate({
        left: '100px',
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) to either `relative`, `absolute`, `fixed` or `sticky`.

`position: static` is the default which instructs the browser to ignore any `top`/`right`/`bottom`/`left` properties.

```js
$('#test').on('click', function() {
    $(this).animate({left: '100px'}, 1000);
});
```

```css
#test {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">Click me!</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

At jQuery v1.6.x and less you can animate numbers, not strings, so use:

```
$('#test').on('click', function() {
    $(this).animate({
        left: 100,
    }, 1000);
});
```

You can also add or reduce values using plus and minus as:

```
$('#test').on('click', function() {
    $(this).animate({
        left: '+=100',
    }, 1000);
});
```

...that would add 100px to current value.

Comment: Correct, he must be missing element position.

Comment: Still it was introduced in jQuery 1.7 or more, no need to downvote.